# webpack-dev-server writeToDisk: true

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

There is a new option:

**writeToDisk: true**

... but I wonder where exactly on the disk are the bundles saved? There is only the *true* option without specifying the destination of the bundle on the disk.

Thx in advance for clearance.

Comment: this is saved where your `output.path` is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bundle will be saved on your output path which you have defined in `webpack.config.js`
The default is `dist` folder for output